# Simple, how do I make multiple lines using an array for an animation in canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am new to coding and Javascript and I'm a little lost. I am trying to create multiple lines that animate on refresh. something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/79zcp/6/

```
        if (min < max) {
    context.beginPath();
    if (direction) {
        context.moveTo(topMinX, topMinY);
        topMinX = topMinX + 2;
        context.lineTo(topMinX, topMaxY);
    } else {
        context.moveTo(topMinX, topMinY);
        topMinY = topMinY + 2;
        context.lineTo(topMaxX, topMinY);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.stroke();
}
```

}

but with multiple lines going down the y axis, spaced about 20 pixels apart.

My teacher suggested making the multiple lines with an array but i'm totally lost.

Comment: You could use an array of x,y values and use lineTo in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forked the Fiddle to create a new one: http://jsfiddle.net/UcrUj/3.
Note that I've changed the functions such that it only works for vertical lines (the `direction` variable is now obsolete).

You should us an array as the x-coordinates. Here, the array is

```
linesX = [20, 40, 60, 80]
```

which specifies 4 lines on the x-coordinates x = 20, x = 40, x = 60, and x = 80.
Now, you run a `for` loop going through each of the x-coordinates, drawing each line individually. Finally the increment is added at the end, `topMinY += 2`, which to clarify is shorthand for `topMinY = topMinY + 2`.